# f# - compiling a dll on arch linux

Tags: linux, dll, f#, archlinux

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question or I'd rather ask on the arch forum, but I am getting some troubles in creating a dll on arch linux.

I had to install the 7.0 version of F# recently and the command "dotnet fsi" works until I hace to execute a .fsx file or the "live" interpreter, but it's not able to perform any of the compiler option [at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options) (in this case "dotnet fsi -a file.fs").
I followed the guide for linux installation on [the official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/install-fsharp#install-f-with-visual-studio-code) (.NET SDK version 7.0), but the error contains an fsi.exe error: "Exception by fsi.exe: System.Exception: Error creating evaluation session: StopProcessingExn".

I have the funny feeling that all my problems starts right from that ".exe", but it should be an installation script intended for linux...

Comment: `fsi` is the REPL interpreter, it doesn't compile to DLLs. Try `dotnet build` instead.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it turned out that my code organization was wrong and your answer is completely correct. Thank you